# Produce the linear and quadratic Taylor polynomials for $f(x)=e^{\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$$f(x)=e^{\cos x},x_0=0$$

I wrote first two terms of Taylor Polynomial of $f(x)$:

$$P_2(x)=e-\frac{e}{2}x^2$$

It is quadratic Taylor Polynomial. but what about linear one? Is it simply $P_1(x)=e$ or I should say it doesn't exist because we don't have $x^1$ in the expression?

Comment: It is indeed $P_1(x)=e+0\cdot x=e$.

Comment: @Gary but I find this on a site:https://www.sscc.edu/home/jdavidso/Math/Catalog/Polynomials/First/First.html   It says "In particular, first degree polynomials are lines which are neither horizontal nor vertical."

Comment: Yes, this is a bit problematic. In general, $P_1(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is called the first-order Taylor polynomial about the point $x_0$ in the literature and they do not assume that $f'(x_0)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $ f $ is an even one, so its second degree Taylor expansion arround $ x_0=0 $,  will be of the form

$$f(x)=e^{\cos(x)}=$$
$$P_2(x)+x^2\epsilon(x)=$$
$$a_0+a_2x^2+x^2\epsilon(x)$$

The tangent line at $ x_0=0 $ is horizontal and its equation is
$$y=P_1(x)=f(0)=e$$